# Is there a way to change the output format of spark-submit

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-submit

I'm running a python script from spark-submit, the stdout from the script is output by spark-submit like this:

```
[dd-MM-yyyy HH:MM] Line1
[dd-MM-yyyy HH:MM] Line2
[dd-MM-yyyy HH:MM] Line3
```

Is there anyway to get it to output like this:

```
Line1
Line2
Line3
```

I know I could just parse the output, but I'm trying to make the code cleaner to read, and ideally I don't want to have to hard code the format of the line being parsed.

Answer (score 0):

Spark use Log4j for logging. Configuration template can be found in `conf/log4j.properties.template`. Copy this file to the same directory with the name `log4j.properties`. Then chane line:

```
log4j.appender.console.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss} %p %c{1}: %m%n
```

to:

```
log4j.appender.console.layout.ConversionPattern=%c{1}: %m%n
```

But i am not sure this is right decision.